# Parsimony and Box Jenkins

Tags: forecasting, arima, model-selection, volatility-forecasting, box-jenkins

Suppose that you want to estimate volatility of stock returns with the arch/garch family. An important step is to estimate the mean equation.

Suppose that you estimated e.g. an ARMA(5,4) model for the mean and you have every reason to suspect that this is an acceptable model (acf-pacf plots, tests, e.t.c).

Is this acceptable in terms of parsimony? Or do we have to lower our standards and accept a model with fewer terms e.g. ARMA(2,2) ? Many papers around do not discuss this part in detail. Some, even proceed by arbitrarily choosing a low-order model for the mean e.g. AR(1) without even discussing their choise.

Comment: Is this for forecasting? (Otherwise you should remove the [tag:forecasting] tag.) Then it would make sense to choose the model with the lowest AIC value. If your goal is forecasting and ARMA(2,2) has a lower AIC value than ARMA(5,4), go for the former. If you goal is different, a different model selection criterion will apply.

Comment: @RichardHardy thank for the responce. Yes, modeling and forecasting volatility. Suppose that ARMA(5,4) has the lowest AIC of all possible models. Lower than ARMA(2,2). It is an appropriate selection. However, I am worried about parsimony since I now have 9 terms. Should I lower my standards to accept a model with fewer terms? The more the parameters the greater the noise.